# Linux TOTP vs SSH Keys

Tags: ssh, security

I am in the middle of a security upgrade task and have been reading a lot of articles around SSH security. I have a question around what is the better method of securing SSH by using SSH Keys or TOTP?

Thanks in advance for any opinions and replies :)

Answer (score 3):

> what is the better method of securing SSH by using SSH Keys or TOTP?

They are completely different things. TOTP is and should be used as the second factor and they are based on the shared secret. This is something you have (token, FreeOTP application with secret key) and if you loose it, you would be screwed up if there was no other factor (they are usually not protected).

On the other side, there are SSH keys that are based on asymmetric cryptography and with the keeping few basic rules (passphrase, PIN on HSM), you can use them as the only authentication (yes, they are widely used).

You question as it is, is too broad.